# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql

I am executing some queries and am getting the following the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$section2' (T_VARIABLE) on line
>   22

Line 22 is:

```
$section2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO learning_style_scores VALUES (5,12,4)");
```

I don't have a clue why I am getting this, I have checked my syntax and all seems to be correct. It basically doesn't like anything after the `$section1` query is executed

**EDIT:**

I understand this is prone to SQL injection but I am doing it like this for testing purposes only.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=questionnaire;host=localhost", "root", ""); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    }


    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }


    $session = md5(session_id());

    // insert section1 data into database
    $section1 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO section1 VALUES (7,"test")');

    $section1->execute();​


    // insert learning style score into database
    $section2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO learning_style_scores VALUES (5,12,4)");

    $section2->execute();​
    ?>
```

Comment: 1. Do you show us here your **full** and **real** code ? 2. Is this the correct file? 3. Please show us your full and exact error message which you get

Comment: @Rizier123 I can reproduce a syntax error locally, exactly as stated.

Comment: You've nothing TO prepare. So use `$db->query`

Comment: @Rizier123 This is all my code, there is nothing else. Apart from HTML markup which has no effect on it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code has some weird characters after the semicolon of this line:

```
$section1->execute();​
$section2->execute();​  //same for this line
```

If you look into a hex editor you see this:

```
24 73 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 31 2d 3e 65 78 65 63 75 74 65 28 29 3b e2 80 8b  
                                                             //^^^^^^^^This bit right here

//And it should look like this:
24 73 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 31 2d 3e 65 78 65 63 75 74 65 28 29 3b
```

See here:

[image]

(Yeah I know my circles aren't the nicest)

And this is how it should look like:

[image]

Solution?

Just write the statement new with your keyboard and your fingers.

Comment: Ha, Confirmed, Just hit delete/backspace after the `;` and the code parses.

Comment: @Scuzzy Yes here this works too! You should notice that if you hit delete after the semicolon that it don't deletes the semicolon, it deletes the weird character

Comment: Alternative solution: applying code formatting (CTRL+SHIFT+F) in Eclipse (presumably other editors as well) automagically gets rid of the extra chars making the code parseable.

Comment: Yes, this was it. I would probably never have figured that out myself, probably the most bizzare issues I've had in my whole time programming. Thank you!

Comment: @user3574492 You're welcome :D!  *most bizzare issues I've had in my whole time programming* until now! Maybe the future will bring a better one.

Comment: @Rizier123 just out of interest, how do you check this in a hex editor?

Comment: @user3574492 I used Notpad++ here and there is just a plugin where you can switch to hex view. But I'm pretty sure there is a plugin for every modern IDE (PhpStorm, Intellij IDEA, Eclipse maybe even for Sublime)

Comment: @user3574492 Then you can install it under extensions->plugin manager available HEX-Editor

Comment: Good catch on the weird `;`