# Using $this for default value in php

Tags: php

```
public function addSpouse($name = ($this->data['gender'] == MALE && empty($name)) ? 'Wife' : 'Husband', $suggest = false)
```

PHP is following for the above line:

`syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)`

`$this` is not allowed in function parameter?

EDIT: function is inside a class

Comment: Of course, not. `$this` is a reference to the instance of a class. What are you going to refer to, if there is no object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T\_VARIABLE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952930/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable)

Comment: addSpouse is inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable ($this->data or any variable) as a default parameter value.
Default function parameter values must be constants.

```
public function addSpouse($name = 'Wife')
```

is correct but not:

```
public function addSpouse($name = $data)
```